# Contract and the transaction that creates the contract

Tags: contract-deployment

Are those different? Blockchain is a list of transactions bundled into blocks. Thus, it is clear that all transactions are recorded in the blockchain. But then where are the contracts stored?

Answer (score 1):

A blockchain is a list of transactions, yes. 
Executing each and every one of those transactions gives you the state of the ledger. This 'state' is the representations of all data, including smart contracts. It is stored on every node of the network.

When you retrieve data from a node, it looks it up in the state which is has stored on it's disk. When you execute a smart contract's function, that execution might alter the state and that alteration is stored.

Some of these transactions in the blockchain are contract deployment transactions. These transactions add smart contracts to the current state. Then, transactions can be added (mined) to the blockchain which alter the state by executing the smart contract's code.

So, a smart contract is not in itself a transaction, it is the result of executing a deployment transaction.

The contract itself is stored in the state, on the disk of each node that has executed each transaction of the blockchain.

Comment: Thank you! From your answer it follows that smart contracts are not stored on the blockchain. Blockchain stores only transactions, and smart contracts are stored on the disk of each node. Why not store transactions on the disk of each node then?

Comment: The blocks with transactions are also stored on the nodes